# jQuery Serialize Array Input

Tags: jquery

How to serialize those array input using jquery to

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
    <input type="text" name="name[0].basketball">
    <input type="text" name="name[0].ball">
    <input type="text" name="name[1].basketball">
    <input type="text" name="name[1].ball">
</form>
```

Something looks like this:

```
[{basketball: 'TestBasketball', Ball: 'TestBall'}, {basketball: 'TestBasketball1', Ball: 'TestBall2'}]
```

JQuery (This code not working, it just get name[0].basketball: 'TestBasketball')

```
$('#myform').serializeArray();
```

Comment: `serializeArray()` cannot give you the output you require. To get that you'd need to build the array manually. I'd suggest looking in to `map()`

Comment: yes im going to post it to my controller. but I don't know why it is not working if i use serialize()

Comment: Don't use dot notation then ... use `name[0][basketball]` format and serialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var ser = [];
$("#myform>input[type=text]").each(function() {
  var idx = parseInt(this.name.split("[")[1]);
  var key = this.name.split(".")[1];
  if (ser[idx]) ser[idx][key]=this.value;
  else ser.push({[key]:this.value});
});
console.log(ser);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="">
  <input type="text" name="name[0].basketball" value="TestBasketball1" />
  <input type="text" name="name[0].ball" value="TestBall1" />
  <input type="text" name="name[1].basketball" value="TestBasketball2">
  <input type="text" name="name[1].ball" value="TestBall2" />
</form>
```